# Autolayout constraint disappearing at runtime

Tags: ios, autolayout, runtime

I have a simple table view cell containing two labels whose positioning constraints disappear at runtime (the width and aspect ration remain). There are no warnings, no errors in the storyboard view, no console log and I don't use size classes.

The views are misplaced (they stick to the top left corner) and when I launch the Debug View Hierarchy there is an exclamation mark on a purple background indicating an ambiguous position. Upon inspection it turns out that the position constraints are not there anymore.

I have tried removing and adding them again, I have compared almost every IB inspector in the view hierarchy with a working implementation and couldn't figure out a difference. I have inspected the views with lldb and the _autolayoutTrace doesn't show the constraints.

I know I can remove the controller in Interface Builder and rebuild it but I would appreciate an insight into debugging that kind of issue.

Here is the part of the storyboard describing the table view controller and prototype cell :

```
<tableViewController id="RTg-bl-d8Z" customClass="ChekListViewController" customModule="Todo_app" customModuleProvider="target" sceneMemberID="viewController">
    <tableView key="view" clipsSubviews="YES" contentMode="scaleToFill" alwaysBounceVertical="YES" dataMode="prototypes" style="plain" separatorStyle="default" rowHeight="-1" estimatedRowHeight="-1" sectionHeaderHeight="28" sectionFooterHeight="28" id="5dF-Vx-S1N">
        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="414" height="896"/>
        <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" widthSizable="YES" heightSizable="YES"/>
        <color key="backgroundColor" systemColor="systemBackgroundColor" cocoaTouchSystemColor="whiteColor"/>
        <prototypes>
            <tableViewCell clipsSubviews="YES" contentMode="scaleToFill" preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins="YES" selectionStyle="default" accessoryType="detailDisclosureButton" indentationWidth="10" reuseIdentifier="checkListItem" id="a6e-eR-CO4" customClass="CheckListItemCell" customModule="Todo_app" customModuleProvider="target">
                <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="28" width="414" height="57.5"/>
                <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask"/>
                <tableViewCellContentView key="contentView" opaque="NO" clipsSubviews="YES" multipleTouchEnabled="YES" contentMode="center" preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins="YES" insetsLayoutMarginsFromSafeArea="NO" tableViewCell="a6e-eR-CO4" id="EUI-T4-UFi" customClass="CheckListItemCell" customModule="Todo_app" customModuleProvider="target">
                    <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="351" height="57.5"/>
                    <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask"/>
                    <subviews>
                        <label opaque="NO" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="left" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" text="✔️" textAlignment="natural" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="KM3-zM-YXK">
                            <rect key="frame" x="28" y="11" width="25.5" height="35.5"/>
                            <constraints>
                                <constraint firstAttribute="width" constant="25" id="uyC-B0-CMt"/>
                                <constraint firstAttribute="width" secondItem="KM3-zM-YXK" secondAttribute="height" multiplier="25:35" id="yPH-cC-BhV"/>
                            </constraints>
                            <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="17"/>
                            <nil key="textColor"/>
                            <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
                        </label>
                        <label opaque="NO" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="left" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" text="Label" textAlignment="natural" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="I1F-jX-unK">
                            <rect key="frame" x="61.5" y="18.5" width="281.5" height="21"/>
                            <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="17"/>
                            <nil key="textColor"/>
                            <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
                        </label>
                    </subviews>
                    <constraints>
                        <constraint firstAttribute="trailingMargin" secondItem="I1F-jX-unK" secondAttribute="trailing" id="2DJ-vu-eZH"/>
                        <constraint firstItem="I1F-jX-unK" firstAttribute="centerY" secondItem="KM3-zM-YXK" secondAttribute="centerY" id="5sk-xI-Lws"/>
                        <constraint firstItem="KM3-zM-YXK" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="EUI-T4-UFi" secondAttribute="leadingMargin" constant="8" id="T2a-1U-YX9"/>
                        <constraint firstItem="I1F-jX-unK" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="KM3-zM-YXK" secondAttribute="trailing" constant="8" id="a2G-6H-iVm"/>
                        <constraint firstItem="KM3-zM-YXK" firstAttribute="bottom" secondItem="EUI-T4-UFi" secondAttribute="bottomMargin" id="c6K-zY-2tu"/>
                        <constraint firstItem="KM3-zM-YXK" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="EUI-T4-UFi" secondAttribute="topMargin" id="z4V-Rz-c6k"/>
                    </constraints>
                </tableViewCellContentView>
                <connections>
                    <outlet property="checkMark" destination="KM3-zM-YXK" id="qY4-JT-7iv"/>
                    <outlet property="textItem" destination="I1F-jX-unK" id="eID-MO-fVV"/>
                    <segue destination="Kuh-LZ-DVA" kind="presentation" identifier="editItem" trigger="accessoryAction" id="DeL-Ql-cQq"/>
                </connections>
            </tableViewCell>
        </prototypes>
        <sections/>
        <connections>
            <outlet property="dataSource" destination="RTg-bl-d8Z" id="34r-cH-2bg"/>
            <outlet property="delegate" destination="RTg-bl-d8Z" id="CsE-gc-hUN"/>
        </connections>
    </tableView>
    <navigationItem key="navigationItem" title="Name of the list" id="05Z-xs-cMG">
        <barButtonItem key="rightBarButtonItem" systemItem="add" id="oSl-fh-Gh3">
            <connections>
                <segue destination="Kuh-LZ-DVA" kind="presentation" identifier="addItem" id="6cn-yq-cSG"/>
            </connections>
        </barButtonItem>
    </navigationItem>
</tableViewController>
```

Comment: First thing -- Do you have multiple Storyboards and/or controllers? If so, a very common "whoops" is working on the wrong object. To make ***sure*** the cell you are working with in Storyboard is the cell your code is using, give the labels different background colors and run the app. Do you see the new background colors?

Comment: I have a single storyboard and I have the right class of controller and the right class of cell, the labels' texts get the right content. I am able to replace the controller with a working one but I haven't been able to locate the difference between the working one and the buggy one and I would like to have a solution to investigate the source of the problem.

Comment: If it's just a single controller (or just a couple controllers) in the Storyboard, post the xml source in your question and we can take a look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, that was not obvious... until it was :)

Somehow - either by an "oops" click or some Xcode / IB quirk - your cell's `Content View` got its class set to `CheckListItemCell`:

[image]

Select the cell's `Content View`, go to the Identity Inspector pane, and change the `Custom Class` back to the default `UIView`:

[image]

Better result:

[image]